# Mapping configuration error in Spring Web Application

Tags: html, spring

I am currently creating a Spring webapp that allows a user to login, register and add books. Currently when the user goes to register (i.e filling out a form and clicking submit button), the page loads the login page as opposed to registering a user (into mySQL db) and opening up their profile page. Everything in the controller suggests to me that the register function should work, but for a reason I can't quite figure out it just prompts the login screen to load and therefore the register does not work. I included a debugger in the `registerUser` controller method and its not printing anything, which leads me to believe that the request isn't being sent to the controller at all. Could it be an issue with the `WebSecurityConfig` or the `MvcConfig` files and how they are mapped/configured. Ill include the relevant code snippets below.

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**", "/register").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }
```

**MvcConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/home").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("home");
        registry.addViewController("/hello").setViewName("hello");
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
        registry.addViewController("/register").setViewName("register");
        registry.addViewController("/profile").setViewName("profile");


    }

}
```

**BookController**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/register", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String register(User user) {
    return "/register";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/registerUser", method=RequestMethod.POST) //name of url... this is what i call. 
public String registerUser(@Valid User user, Model model, BindingResult errors) {
    System.out.println("User" + user);
    userR.save(user); 
    return "hello";
}


@RequestMapping(value= "/login")
public String login() {
    return "login"; 
}
```

This is the form that I am trying to run via the controller. 
**register.html**

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/registerUser}" method="post" th:object="${user}" >
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>UserName:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{userName}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{password}" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
      Already have an account? <a href="/login">Click here</a> to log in.

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `viewController`you shouldn't use common controllers, and vice versa.

> Use it in static cases when there is no Java controller logic to
>   execute before the view generates the response.

And you must return view name, don't return path.

```
"/register"
```

is incorrect.
If you use Spring MVC add `@EnableWebMvc` annotation, if Spring Boot make sure what SpringMvc present in classpath. It's necessary for spring be able to configure mapping feauteres.